# OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll and "Invalid pointer" or "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" COM errors

Tags: com, autoit, openhardwaremonitor

I would use the Open Hardware Monitor library to read some values about the hardware instead of executing OpenHardwareMonitor.exe and reading from WMI, so I used RegAsm to register the types in the registry (so I could run the classes in the library as COM objects).
First of all I've changed COMVISIBLE property of the project to TRUE and I've recompiled the library with MSBuild.exe.
I would convert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853656) script to Autoit but when I tried to call any method, I get the error: "Invalid pointer". or "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". 
I don't understand why I get that error, I don't think it's cause RegAsm because it gives me a warning but then it does its job registering the types, this is what it adds to the registry:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Record\{1FD2DBF2-D8C3-3E57-B448-37196EB12D9C}\0.6.0.11]
"Class"="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.ControlMode"
"Assembly"="OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.6.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Users/gianluca/Desktop/lavoro/openhardwaremonitorlib.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer]
@="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer\CLSID]
@="{5E652471-D269-3567-BB38-DCEBFF5669CF}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5E652471-D269-3567-BB38-DCEBFF5669CF}]
@="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5E652471-D269-3567-BB38-DCEBFF5669CF}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer"
"Assembly"="OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.6.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Users/gianluca/Desktop/lavoro/openhardwaremonitorlib.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5E652471-D269-3567-BB38-DCEBFF5669CF}\InprocServer32\0.6.0.11]
"Class"="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer"
"Assembly"="OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.6.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Users/gianluca/Desktop/lavoro/openhardwaremonitorlib.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5E652471-D269-3567-BB38-DCEBFF5669CF}\ProgId]
@="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5E652471-D269-3567-BB38-DCEBFF5669CF}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Record\{E4E64F96-C708-381E-8380-93DF59B324B0}\0.6.0.11]
"Class"="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.HardwareType"
"Assembly"="OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.6.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Users/gianluca/Desktop/lavoro/openhardwaremonitorlib.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Record\{DFC56287-93E1-3B82-8F95-5F4268CB0401}\0.6.0.11]
"Class"="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.SensorType"
"Assembly"="OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.6.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Users/gianluca/Desktop/lavoro/openhardwaremonitorlib.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Record\{6042D116-95C1-3C8A-B8DC-D0E6C8F5BA07}\0.6.0.11]
"Class"="OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.SensorValue"
"Assembly"="OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.6.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Users/gianluca/Desktop/lavoro/openhardwaremonitorlib.dll"
```

This is what OLEView shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa1NO.jpg
And this is the simple script that generates the error:

```
#RequireAdmin
$RegAsm_path = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" ; CHECK YOUR VERSION!!!
$foo = Run($RegAsm_path & " /codebase /nologo OpenHardwareMonitorlib.dll", "", @SW_HIDE, 0x2 + 0x4)
$std = _Read_Std($foo)
MsgBox(0,$foo,$std)

$oMyError = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error","MyErrFunc")

$cp = ObjCreate("OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer")
If IsObj($cp) Then MsgBox(0,"OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer","Object created")
$cp.Open() ; <--------------- ERROR

RunWait($RegAsm_path & " /nologo /unregister OpenHardwareMonitorlib.dll", "", @SW_HIDE)

Func MyErrFunc()
    $HexNumber=hex($oMyError.number,8)
    Msgbox(0,"","We intercepted a COM Error !" & @CRLF & _
        "Number is: " & $HexNumber & @CRLF & _
        "Windescription is: " & $oMyError.windescription & @CRLF & _
        "Source is: " & $oMyError.source & @CRLF & _
        "Description is: " & $oMyError.description & @CRLF & _
        "Script line is: " & $oMyError.scriptline)
    RunWait($RegAsm_path & " /nologo /unregister OpenHardwareMonitorlib.dll", "", @SW_HIDE)
    Exit
Endfunc

Func _Read_Std($handle)
    Local $s
    While 1
        $s &= StdoutRead($handle)
        If @error Then ExitLoop
        $s &= StderrRead($handle)
        If @error Then ExitLoop
    WEnd
    Return $s
EndFunc
```

First of executing the script, you need to check your .NET Framework version on the 2nd line.
 [This](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=44441) is an archive that contains the script and library

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding #AutoIt3Wrapper_UseX64=N to the script to run it as a 32 Bit COM object

Comment: It is by default, however sometimes the error is "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." instead of "invalid pointer"

Comment: Please use the comments on the question to seek clarification, not the answers section.